# Consulta SQL y pasarlo a un intent

Tags: android-studio, sql-server, sql, android-intent

formulé una pregunta sobre como pasar datos entre actividades, y me respondieron bien, pero mi problema ahora es que no yo no necesito pasar una cadena simple o un entero, necesito pasar una consulta SQLserver, meterla en el intent y ya pues pasarla a la otra actividad para que ahí me la muestre, pero no sé como hacerlo, llevo un rato intentándolo y no puedo, alguien me puede hechar un cable? dejo el código por aquí, gracias!!

```
ListView listView;
TextView idtext;
EditText etFiltrar;
String where = "";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listado);
    setupActionBAR();
    etFiltrar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFiltrrar);

    etFiltrar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            where = etFiltrar.getText().toString();
            mostrarClientes();
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMostrar);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;
            idtext = (TextView) vg.findViewById(R.id.id);
            Log.i("Click", position + " " + idtext.getText());
         // ESTO SOLO MUESTRA UN TOAST CON LA POSITION + ID DE TABLA
           //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position= " + position + " ID=" + idtext.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           enviardatos();
        }
    });
    mostrarClientes();
}
public void enviardatos(){

            Intent intent = new Intent(Listado.this,ClienteEspecifico.class);
            intent.putExtra("nombre",/*Aquí deberia pasar la variable */);
            startActivity(intent);
}
private void setupActionBAR(){
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        //Mostrar el boton en el ActionBar
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("Lista de Clientes");
    }
}

public void mostrarClientes() {
    HashMap<String, String> clientes = new HashMap<>();
    ConectarHaciaSQL consql;
    consql = new ConectarHaciaSQL();
    Connection cn = consql.conexionBD();
    try {
        Statement pst = cn.createStatement();
        String sel;
        sel = "select CLI.idcliente, CLI.NombreComercial, UC.telefono1 from clientes as CLI" +
                " left join ubicacionesClientes as UC on UC.idcliente = CLI.idCliente ";
        if (where != "") {
            sel = sel + " where CLI.NombreComercial like '%" + where + "%'";
        }
        ;
        sel = sel + " ORDER BY CLI.idcliente ASC";
        //Ejecuta el query del SQL
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sel);
        //Recorre la tabla del SQL
        while (rs.next()) {
            clientes.put(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));
        }

        if (rs != null) {

        } else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No hay nada ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (rs != null)
            rs.close();

        List<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.list_items,
                new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name});

        Iterator it = clientes.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            HashMap<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            resultMap.put("First Line", pair.getKey().toString());
            resultMap.put("Second Line", pair.getValue().toString());
            listItems.add(resultMap);
        }
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.i("Error", "Error al abrir o crear la base de datos" + e);
    }
}
```

Cómo veis tengo una consulta SQL que me muestra nombres en un listview, pero ahora necesito a través de otra consulta, (supongo) como he dicho, mostrar por ejemplo nombre, teléfono y algunos datos más en un textview, o a poder ser cada uno en un EditText, si alguien me contesta bien le amaré. Gracias!!!